# switching image on timed event in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to switch the displayed image in an UIImageView to different images based on an timed event by defining the what image should be displayed by I and the app works but when the timer gets to 5 the app crashes. if anyone can help me out then that would be great (also the Ad is the beginning of the image name so AD_1 - AD_4)

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

//this is for declaring all the profile buttons
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Icon_8: UIButton!


//this is used to swich the images
var i = Int(1)

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

//this is for the view
@IBOutlet weak var ad_view: UIView!

//this is for when the user swipes left
@IBAction func Icon_Swipe_Left(_ sender: Any) {
    Icon_1.isHidden = true
    Icon_2.isHidden = true
    Icon_3.isHidden = true
    Icon_4.isHidden = true

    Icon_5.isHidden = false
    Icon_6.isHidden = false
    Icon_7.isHidden = false
    Icon_8.isHidden = false
}

//this is when the user swipes right
@IBAction func Icon_Swipe_Right(_ sender: Any) {
    Icon_1.isHidden = false
    Icon_2.isHidden = false
    Icon_3.isHidden = false
    Icon_4.isHidden = false

    Icon_5.isHidden = true
    Icon_6.isHidden = true
    Icon_7.isHidden = true
    Icon_8.isHidden = true
}

// this is for decareing the image frame for the adds
@IBOutlet weak var Ad_Frame: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //this is for showing the fist set of icons
    Icon_1.isHidden = false
    Icon_2.isHidden = false
    Icon_3.isHidden = false
    Icon_4.isHidden = false
    //this is for hideing the second set of icons
    Icon_5.isHidden = true
    Icon_6.isHidden = true
    Icon_7.isHidden = true
    Icon_8.isHidden = true

    self.Ad_Frame.image = UIImage(named: "AD_\(i)")
}

@objc func fire()
{
    i += 1
    self.Ad_Frame.image = UIImage(named: "AD_\(i)")
}
```

}

Comment: Helpful hint: you should learn about outlet collections.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1:  you say you have images AD_1 - AD_4 - that's only four images, so it won't cope with the fifth!  I'm assuming you mean AD_1 - AD_5

2:  More importantly, you start with `i = 1`, and then add 1 before trying to display the image, so you're actually trying to display images 2...6.

Increment `i` after displaying the image, not before

Comment: I tried to start off with displaying the fist image and then switching the image but I switched it around and it still crashed

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment or its relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Change fire so that it starts over once 5 is reached

```
@objc func fire() {
    self.Ad_Frame.image = UIImage(named: "AD_\(i)")
    i += 1
    if i > 4 { i = 1 }
}
```

Off-topic but I would recommend renaming `i` to something more readable like `counter` for instance. Single letter variables are not recommended apart from in `for` loops. Also when declaring it you don't need to call `Int(...)` but assign the value directly instead, `var counter = 1`